# Can't make DRV8833 work with Raspberry Pico

Tags: pi-pico, dc-motor

I'm building a toy car for my nephew. I want to drive a small DC motor with a Raspberry Pico with a DRV8833 motor controller. The controller is powered through the Pico. I seems fine, there is voltage between its GND and VCC pins and it also lights up. I send high voltage through the GPIO16 of the Pico to the IN1 (or IN3, tried both) of the controller and low through GPIO17 to IN2 (or IN4) this should drive the motor forward through the output pins. Unfortunately no matter what I do there's no voltage at all on the out pins (neither between OUT1 and OUT2 or OUT3 and OUT4). I tested a 2nd unit of the controller to see if the first one was faulty, no luck.

(Notice that the motor on the picture is on the wrong output, nevertheless I''m testing voltage with the multimeter on all outputs)

[image]

Comment: `controller is powered through the Pico` ... you can only control through the Pico ... power for motor has to come from an external power supply

Comment: Why is that? If I plug the motor into the VCC of the controller it works just fine.

Comment: overloading the Pico could turn it into an expensive fuse

Comment: The Pico 3V3 max current is 300mA, and the DC motor is max current is 150mA, this should not be a problem. Anyway, there's absolutely no voltage on the output pins of the controller. Ampers are not the problem.

Comment: jsotola answered your question in his comment. If you choose to ignore that advice, well, that's your business...  but why do you come here with questions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP got an answer in a comment, but chooses to ignore it.

Comment: There seems some confusion somewhere.  This article might clarify - https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/dc-motors-raspberry-pi-pico.

Comment: One more thing: Remember to activate the DRV8833 by disabling the sleeper by shorting the EEP jumper: How to troubleshoot a DRV8833 motor driver module problem? Asked 3 years ago, Viewed 3k times Update 2020nov17hkt1511
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531470/how-to-troubleshoot-a-drv8833-motor-driver-module-problem
The OP has confirmed that he forgot to enable the DRV8833 by shorting the EEP (Sleep) jumper cap, therefore causing all zero's at output pins. I hope to make a follow up remark later, including a reminder for future readers and DRV8833 newbies.

Comment: And you might also need to short the sense resistor jumpers (Appendix C of my answer below): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/125089/rpi-python-drv8833-motor-driver-setting-up-and-troubleshooting-dc-motor-driving.